# Why am I getting error while using if statement with assign in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

```
module latch(clk,d,q);
    input clk,d;
    output q;
    
    if(clk==1)
    assign q = d;
endmodule
```

Why am I getting error in the above code?

Comment: Can you add the details of the error in your question? Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: Error: Peak virtual memory: 4690 megabytes Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at latch.v(4) near text: "if";  expecting "endmodule". Check for and fix any syntax errors that appear immediately before or at the specified keyword.

Answer (score 4):

`if` is not a top level block inside a module. It should be used inside an `always`, or `initial` (if for simulation purposes) block, or other legal blocks. While `assign` is. (`generate` is not taken into consideration, for simplicity)

I guess what you want to achieve is:

```
module latch(clk, d, q);
input clk, d;
output q;
reg q;
always@(*)begin
  if(clk)begin
    q = d;
  end
end
```

Comment: So, I can't use any control flow statements in conjunction in "assign"?

Comment: You can use ?: like assign q = clk ? d : q; but not all tools will be happy with this.